# Rate Limit plugin causing high response time for API registered behind Kong API gateway?

Tags: api, nginx, rate-limiting, kong

On kong 0.8, rate-limit plugin is leading to high response time. When calling directly, api response time is ~200-250ms. When called through kong it is giving response in time ~1000-2000ms (when rate-limit plugin is enabled) and ~300ms (with rate-limit pplugin disabled).

Also "config.policy" parameter for rate-limit plugin is not working (may be because of older version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Kong and try again.